# expect command in Solaris 11

Tags: solaris, expect

New to expect command, In Solaris 11 the `expect` package is included, and I understand from Linux it's very useful for automation.

Am trying to create around 10 users and set password for the users by a script.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect 
spawn /usr/bin/passwd user1
expect "New password: \n" 
send "Userpass123$\r" 
expect "Re-enter new Password: \n" 
send "Userpass123$\r"
```

The password is being set correctly, but its taking almost 20 seconds to set the password for a single user,

Find the output below

```
JUDI-DEV-01# time /tmp/123
spawn /usr/bin/passwd user1
New Password:
Re-enter new Password:
real    0m20.023s
user    0m0.005s
sys     0m0.005s
JUDI-DEV-01#
```

Please help me in fetching the user id , UID , GID , home dir, from a file and to create the user accounts 
example file data is /tmp/userlist

```
user1:150:20:App User1:/export/home/user1:/bin/ksh
user2:151:20:App User2:/export/home/user2:/bin/ksh
user3:152:20:App User3:/export/home/user3:/bin/ksh

dbuser1:201:30:db user1:/export/home/dbuser1:/usr/bin/ksh
dbuser2:202:30:db user1:/export/home/dbuser2:/usr/bin/ksh
```

I know to separate the values to different variable in shell script, not sure how it works in expect

Answer (score 2):

After sending the password for the second time, add `expect eof`. This will ensure the completion of the program.

```
send "Userpass123$\r"
expect eof
```

To split the values, you can use `split` command

```
% split "dbuser1:201:30:db user1:/export/home/dbuser1:/usr/bin/ksh" :
dbuser1 201 30 {db user1} /export/home/dbuser1 /usr/bin/ksh
%
```